# Trying to Use MFMailComposeViewController From Within a Modal View

Tags: ios, modalviewcontroller, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I've successfully implemented a modal view controller from my map based app that shows an options panel below the map using a partial curl transition.

From here, I'd like to implement a button that allows users to use the MFMailComposeViewControl to contact me via email.  I've implemented the code below, but the application crashes every time I tap the button & presentModalView is called.

I know that the issue must be related to trying to call a modal view on top of another, but I can't seem to figure out how to solve.

**Here's the crash message:**

> *** Assertion failure in -[UIWindowController transition:fromViewController:toViewController:target:didEndSelector:],
>   /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-1914.84/UIWindowController.m:188

```
- (IBAction)sendSupportMail:(id)sender{

    // log this in the debugger 
    NSLog(@"You hit the send support mail button.");


    // dismiss the page curled options view
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];    


    // check to see if email is available; if so, compose message
    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
    {
        MFMailComposeViewController *mailer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];

        mailer.mailComposeDelegate = self;

        [mailer setSubject:@"Subject here"];

        NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"first@mail.com", @"second@mail.com", nil];
        [mailer setToRecipients:toRecipients];

        NSString *emailBody = @"Body Copy";
        [mailer setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];

         [self presentModalViewController:mailer animated:YES];
        NSLog(@"Present Mailer Called");

        [mailer release];
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Failure"
                                                        message:@"Your device doesn't support the composer sheet"
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }

}
```

Comment: Does the error go away if you comment out the line `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];`?

Comment: No such luck, unfortunately.  Continues to crash with the same error code :(